# Horizontal alignment of footnote numbers with hang-option of footmisc

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, footmisc

I would like to have a horizontal space between the footnote numbers and the text of the footnote. For this I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[ragged,hang]{footmisc}

\usepackage{dblfnote}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{A blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how the letters are written and an impression of the look.}

\setcounter{footnote}{10}
\blindtext\footnote{A blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how the letters are written and an impression of the look.}

\setcounter{footnote}{100}
\blindtext\footnote{A blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how the letters are written and an impression of the look.}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

The problem here is that the numbers are not aligned correctly (I would like to have the "1" above the second 1 in "11" and "11" above "01" in "101"). If I do not use the `hang`-option of the `footmisc`-package the alignment is correct but there is no horizontal space between the numbers and the text:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem I see is the alignment when only one or two digit footnote numbers are in the page. What to do?

Comment: I do not know if I understand your question correctly but what I want to achieve is to align the footnote numbers always on the right with a space between the number and the text of the footnote.

Answer (score 4):

You can patch `\@makefntext`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[ragged,hang]{footmisc}

\usepackage{dblfnote}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@makefntext
  {\@makefnmark\hss}
  {\hss\@makefnmark\space}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{A blind text like this gives you information about the
  selected font, how the letters are written and an impression of the look.}

\setcounter{footnote}{10}
\blindtext\footnote{A blind text like this gives you information about the
  selected font, how the letters are written and an impression of the look.}

\setcounter{footnote}{100}
\blindtext\footnote{A blind text like this gives you information about the
  selected font, how the letters are written and an impression of the look.}

\end{document}
```

[image]